# "If" conditionals produce html 302

Tags: python

**update 0**
[This link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)  describes 302 code but I cannot understand the technical language. Is it important that the 302 code comes after the `self.response.out.write(` but the templates `unexpected.html` is never triggered? That is the part I could use the most help on.

```
INFO     2012-09-24 01:15:10,182 dev_appserver.py:2967] "POST /reserve/Rogers/1 HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

I am worried that some other code than `self.response.out.write(` must be used to get to `unexpected.html` or that there is a flaw in the **structure** of my use of the conditionals. I am not expecting anyone to read the details of my code, though.
**update 0**

**update 1**
One line of code was extra and was commented out in my actual code, has been removed. Coincidentally it was a partial `if` statement, to confuse matters more.
**update 1**

**update 2**
I have used the code below with different values of a,b,c,d and verified that all branches work as I expect. So I believe the structure of my code is not the problem. I guess I need to look further at the `self.response.out.write(` process more.

```
a=3
b=3
c=5
d=6
if c<d:
    print "c<d"
if a<b:
    print "a<b"
elif a==b:
    print "a=b"
else:
    print "not a<=b"
print "not a b"
```

**update 2**

This code has a pair of nested for loops enclosing a if/elif/elif/elif/else. The first if encloses an if which in turn encloses an if, an if/else and an uncondition phrase. I have omitted several lines for the sake of brevity.

Focus on the 10th line down which begins `self.response.out.write(` , and the two similar lines about 7 more lines down which also begin `self.response.out.write(` . Those lines are each supposed to send the user to a template named `unexpected.html` where the user is advised to press an "Ok" button to be sent somewhere to fix an error in their inputs.

The problem is that I am getting 302 error and processing continues to the code just below this code.

Is there something wrong with my conditionals, or what?

```
for courtname in courtnames:
    for time in times:
    if name == hiddenname:
        pass
    elif name != hiddenname and hiddenname == "":
        #check early and late
        if (res-utime)<timedelta(hours=minBefore[1]):
        template_values = {'trans':trans,'location_id':location_id}
        path = os.path.join(TEMPLATE_DIR, 'unexpected.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, \
            template_values))
        if endtime.endTime<[utime.hour,utime.minute]:
        if (res-utime)>timedelta(days=1+maxBefore[0], \
            hours=maxBefore[1],maxutes=maxBefore[2]):
            template_values = {'trans':trans,'location_id':location_id}
            path = os.path.join(TEMPLATE_DIR, 'unexpected.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(path, \
                template_values))
        else:
        if (res-utime)>timedelta(days=maxBefore[0], \
            hours=maxBefore[1],minutes=maxBefore[2]):
            template_values = {'trans':trans,'location_id':location_id}
            path = os.path.join(TEMPLATE_DIR, 'unexpected.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(path, \
                template_values))
        tempres.append([time, int(year), int(intMonth), \
            int(intWeekday), name,hiddenname,court_id, \
            weekday,weekday_key,int(day),0])
    elif name != hiddenname and name!="":
        #check early and late
        conflict = True
        tempres.append([time, int(year), int(intMonth), \
            int(intWeekday), name,hiddenname,court_id, \
            weekday,weekday_key,int(day),1])
    elif hiddenname != "" and name == "":
        conflict = True
        tempres.append([time, int(year), int(intMonth), \
            int(intWeekday), name,hiddenname,court_id, \
            weekday,weekday_key,int(day),2])
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: This code feels like it could use a method extraction refactoring; you've got a lot of duplicated logic and only a few key parameters change.  I would strongly advise that you start from there, and you may wind up exposing/solving your problem.

Comment: "Sparse is better than dense."  Code which is too dense is hard to read and hard to detect errors in.

Comment: By framework, do you mean jinja2? I don't know what method extraction refactoring is. Do you mean my code is dense or sparse.

Comment: Your code is very dense, making it unreadable.  Refactoring it by method extraction implies that you take the parts common to your if-elif-else blocks, create one function for it, and make the method easier to understand and debug.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please take a new look at my question.